# How to add an icon inside the appBar? - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to add an `icon` **right next to** the title `my app name` of the app (the icon has to be **on the right**).

Here is the appBar:

```
 appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'my app name',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'OpenSansBold',
              fontSize: 26.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

It doesn't have to be a clickable icon, it is just the logo of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children:[
               Text(
                 'my app name',
                 style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSansBold',
                    fontSize: 26.0,
                 ),
               ),   
               Icon(
                 Icons.audiotrack,
                 color: Colors.green,
                 size: 30.0,
               ),
             ]
          )
        ),
```

also, you can change `mainAxisAlignment` for aligning these items or change their order to show the `icon` at the start or the end of the text. The result is as follow:
[image]

---

**Update**
if you want to add an `image` instead of an `icon`, try this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children:[
               Text(
                 'my app name',
                 style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSansBold',
                    fontSize: 26.0,
                 ),
               ),   
               Image(image: AssetImage('your directory'));
             ]
          )
        ),
```

note that first, you should add your image to the `asset` section of `pubspec.yaml` file as follow:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - Your directory
```

for more info see [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

Comment: What if I already have an icon inside a folder? How could I import it?

Comment: is it an image? if so, I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much @Abbasihsn